Solution for find all positive integers a,b,c that satisfies $a^3+b+1=(b^2-c^2)^2$
I found this in a manga I was reading and it already has the answers laid out:
$(6,8,7); (46,7,19)$
I was wondering how someone even starts with this problem, I got to
$a^3+b+1=(b^2-c^2)^2$
$(a+1)(a^2-a+1)+b=[(b-c)(b+c)]^2$
And yeah that's it. I'm not too advanced in Algebraic Manipulation and I would like to find some advice!

I think one starts out by programming a computer to search for solutions. You can't guarantee you'll get all the solutions that way, but do you know for a fact that those two are the only solutions?

Those are the only positive integer solutions with $b \le 1000$ and $c \le 1000$.

$(665, 8575, 8574)$ is another solution.

@Cosmic, I take it you found that by computer search, and not by "Algebraic Manipulation"?

Which manga @Ethan Jairo V Panilag

@GerryMyerson Yep, I ran a program for $b,c\leq 10,000$ and this popped out. The solution set probably has something to do with elliptic curves where you can generate larger and larger solutions through some method I can't completely recall right now.

Working mod 3, one should be able to generate the 2nd and 3rd solutions. I will add an answer later (too long for a comment :) )

@Cosmic, it's a 4th degree equation in three variables, so a surface, not a curve. Well, it might be a surface that contains an elliptic curve.

Oh my... I did check (665, 8575, 8584) and it did return true; so that does suggest the manga is wrong. But still, I would like to find if there is a pattern to this given it probably should. As for the manga, I have no idea the name. I was just walking around Kinokuniya Tokyo and stumbled on this manga with the page containing this problem. I would like to think there are other people interested in this problem because of that book ^^

If $c=b+h$, and you treat $h$ as a constant, then it is an actual elliptic curve.  For example, the one with $h=-1$ has those two solutions found already.

The line between those two solutions give a third solution $(a,b,c)=(5,-5,-6)$ or $(5,25/4,21/4)$

I found a manga with diophantine equations (but not the equation we're discussing): https://mangakakalot.com/chapter/pg921118/chapter_41

(112900, -1354817, 1354831)

The manga is "Houkago no Idol ni wa Himitsu ga aru" in chapter 42

Too long for a comment: It can be more helpful if we manipulate like this:
$a^3+b+1=(b^2-c^2)^2$
$a^3+b=(b^2-c^2)^2-1=[M=(b^2-c^2)-1][N=(b^2-c^2)+1]$
Right hand side can be a multiple of odd or even couples,also one factor may be equal to unity.That is $a$ and $b$ may have a common divisor or can be prime to each other. For example:
$RHS(M, N): (2,4), (4, 6), \cdot\cdot\cdot (14, 16)\cdot\cdot\cdot$
take for example $ (14, 16)$ we have:
$a^3+b=[b^2-c^2-1=14][b^2-c^2+1=16]$
$2(b^2-c^2)=30\Rightarrow b^2-c^2=15$
$(b-c)(b+c)=1\times 15 $
which gives $b=8, c=7$
$a^3=14\times 16-8=216=6^3\rightarrow a=6$
For solution $(665, 8575, 8574)$ we have:
$b-c=8575-8574=1$
$b+c=8575+8574=17149$
$b^2-c^2=17149$
$(17149-1)(17149+1)=17148\times 17150$
So $(M, N)=(17148, 17150)$ belongs to this set.
The solution $(46, 7, 19)$ deduces that we may have $c>b$, in this case we have:
$[(7^2-19^2)-1][(7^2-19^2)+1]=(-313)(-311)-7=97336=46^3$
In this case $M$ and $N$ blognes to the following set:
$RHS (M,N): \cdot\cdot\cdot (-313, -311)\cdot\cdot\cdot (1,3), (3,5)\cdot\cdot\cdot$
We may conclude that there may be no limit for solutions.
